# Migrate a legacy application that uses MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, master-slave-replication

I have been working on the migration of a legacy ecommerce web application to a new server with far hardened security.

I have found an aspect with the MySQL server that I am not acquainted with and I am looking for some guidance here.

The admin side of the ecommerce app has its online instance and a local instance as well.

The local instance, running over an intranet, connects to the MySQL server of the online instance through a replication mechanism.

Here is some information on the replication aspect:

```
Server version: 5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log (Ubuntu)

mysql> SHOW SLAVE HOSTS;
+-----------+------+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| Server_id | Host | Port | Master_id | Slave_UUID                           |
+-----------+------+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|         1 |      | 3306 |         2 | 6a3c1b11-cda3-11e4-8520-b083fede55b6 |
+-----------+------+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+

mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+------+------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Id        | User        | Host              | db   | Command          | Time     | State                                                                       | Info                  |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+------+------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|         1 | system user |                   | NULL | Connect          | 43976299 | Waiting for master to send event                                            | NULL                  |
|         2 | system user |                   | NULL | Connect          |        6 | Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it | NULL                  |
| 105155584 | username    | ***.***.*.*:***** | NULL | Binlog Dump GTID |   497652 | Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated       | NULL                  |
| 106031746 | root        | localhost         | NULL | Query            |        0 | init                                                                        | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+------+------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

**Will it work the same if the local instance connects to the master instead of the slave?**

The MySQL server does not have any kind of performance issue, the load avg never goes above 2.0 for a 12 core cpu.

Comment: Since a single connection won't use more than one core, a load avg of 1.0 _might_ be a red flag.

Comment: "Will it work the same" -- Performance-wise, it depends on network latency.  The results should be the same.  Be aware that you must _not_ write to a Slave.